# why in this sentence мочЬ is feminin?

Tags: грамматика

in this sentence:
Скажи мне, где мы находимся (есть), мы находимся (есть) очень далеко от дома, сегодня облачно могла бы идти дождь
why the мочЬ is in feminin gender? is it for an implied погода?
thanks

Comment: The sentence is grammatically wrong. Where did you get it from? It should be `...мог бы идти дождь`.

Comment: It's in feminine because it's wrong. Correct is мог and мог is masculine.

Comment: That's why It sounded me odd. I copied from my textbook. Thank you very much!

Comment: Besides, the sentence looks really strange. Usually Russian people tend to avoid unneeded verbs like this: `Где мы (сейчас)? Мы очень далеко от дома.`

Answer (score 3):

Unless  *могла бы идти* is separated with e.g. commas as a form of address to a feminine addressee, the sentence is grammatically wrong.

The mistake derives from difficulty most non-native speakers face when trying to distinguish from each other masculine and feminine words ending in the soft sign.

For example, **дождь** is masculine, but **рожь** is feminine. Then, again, **медведь** is masculine while **подать** (with the stressed o) is feminine. One could hope for  any monosyllabic word being feminine, but, alas, **кость** is feminine while **гость** is not. However, any word ending in **-сть** or **-нь** and deriving from an adjective is by rule a feminine one, e.g. *радость, гадость, пакость, синь, зелень, теплынь, пьянь.*

Comment: *Подать* with the stressed _а_ is a verb. Did you mean "stressed _о_"?

Comment: The subject of the question has no relation to distinguishing masculine/feminine nouns. It's not about noun "мочь", it's about a verb.

Comment: @Alex S. Pls don't make the things more complicated than they already are. The topic of the question and the question itself contains a presupposition of feminine gender in the phrase the verb being a noun; since I define a language as a space of probabilities within a given grammatical matrix, the reasons of the possible mistake in the interpretation should also be considered. Hence, my answer is topic-relevant :-)

Comment: The question is why могла is used in the sentence _(and not мог)_. Please read the question (and the comments to it) carefully. There is not a single word about мочь being a noun.

Comment: As you might notice, in my answer I refer to the initial mistake of the speaker, and the reason of the mistake derive from the speaker's wrong assumption дождь (and not мочь) being a noun governing the verb мочь.

Comment: The OP does not assume that дождь is feminine. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: There is nothing about assuming or not that *дождь* is feminine in the question, it is in comments below. btw, separating *могла бы идти* with commas doesn't help here.

Comment: Pls use some logic. The feminine form of the verb is governed by a [errouneously presumed] feminine form of дождь. And, btw. re-read my answer as well. Hope this helps :-)